# C function returning a string

Tags: c, malloc, free

I tried to create a sort of `toString` function in C like this:

```
struct esploratore {
    char nome[20];
    char cognome[20];
    int nascita;
    int morte;
};

char *esploratoreToString(esploratore e) {
    char *s = (char*) malloc(50 * sizeof(char));
    snprintf(s, 50,
             "%s %s %d %d",
             e.nome, e.cognome, e.nascita, e.morte);
    return s;
}
```

and use it in `main` this way:

```
printf("%s", esploratoreToString(e));
```

it works, but the problem is: will the memory assigned by the malloc be ever freed?

is this the only solution?

```
char *s = esploratoreToString(e);
...
printf("%s\n\n", s);
free(s);
```

Comment: No, it won't be freed unless _you_ free it in the calling function once you're done with the steing

Answer (score 2):

In your original code the memory will not be freed.  This is a memory leak.

To call this function properly you'll have to do

```
char *s = esploratoreToString(e);
printf("%s", s);
free(s);
```

There is not really any way around this, if you are going to have `esploratoreToString` do the allocation.  Dynamically allocated objects in C do not ever free themselves.  (C++ is another story...)

(Of course `esploratoreToString` should check that `malloc` succeeds before proceeding...)

Comment: i relized it and modified the question. TY

Comment: Well, if `malloc()` fails, the very first byte that `snprintf()` writes to the resulting `NULL` pointer will safely crash the process on virtually all preemptive multitasking systems. Yes, it's UB, and yes, the pedantic approach is to check for it, but most software does not need to worry.

Comment: I would be more worried about the use of `snprintf()` over `asprintf()` than about the missing `NULL` check: Virtually any use of `snprintf()` has the potential to produced truncated results that may or may not make bad things happen. This class of errors is totally unnecessary and easily avoidable by using `asprintf()` instead. It would actually simplify the code by avoiding the `malloc()` call altogether.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. This is a common idiom in C: the callee allocates memory and *transfers ownership* to the caller. That means that the caller now is responsable for freeing the allocated block.

Answer (score 0):

The memory allocated by `malloc()` is freed when you call `free()` otherwise it will be freed when the process exits.  As design right now, the calling code is responsible for freeing the memory once it's done with it. Alternatively, you could redesign `exploratoreToString()` to a provide a buffer and it's size as an argument.

Answer (score 0):

There's an alternative, in which you provide the buffer:

```
char *esploratoreToString(esploratore *e, char *buf, int bufsz) {
    snprintf(buf, bufsz,
             "%s %s %d %d",
             e.nome, e.cognome, e.nascita, e.morte);
    return buf;
}

...

int main()
{
    char buf[100];
    esploratore exp = {...};

    printf("%s\n", esploratoreToString(&exp, buf, sizeof buf);
}
```

So you can allocate it dynamically, or as an automatic stack allocated buffer.

Another alternative is to returna a pointer to a statically allocated buffer, as in:

```
char *esploratoreToString(esploratore *e) {
    static char buf[50];
    snprintf(buf, bufsz,
             "%s %s %d %d",
             e.nome, e.cognome, e.nascita, e.morte);
    return buf;
}
```

But this has the problem that it is not reentrant, and also if you need to call it twice in the same call to `printf(3)` (in `main`) the second call will overwrite the buffer and you will get a strange behaviour due to overwritting one result with the next and printing twice the same thing.

Comment: This version has no way of detecting when the characters did not fit in the buffer , may or may not be important to OP's use case

Comment: Of course not... but I think that's not a problem, as the question just does the same as I.

Comment: From the outside you have better environment context to decide what kind of buffer you pass down.